# How to compare $_POST to existing Text in table?

Tags: php, android, sql

I'm developing a mobile application for android and I'm trying to compare a variable on the phone to a variable already in the database, so that I can insert it if it's new and update it if it already exists.

```
$name_check = $_POST['Name'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name = $name_check");
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
// Update entry
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work as this block is skipped over and goes to my else block where a new entry is written, so I end up with loads of entries instead of updating one.

I have another field in the table called "Level", and when I compare against that it seems to work, which just confuses me further.

If anyone has any insight into how to do this or why it's not working for me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your code is insecure and can easily  be injected.

Comment: I'm aware, I'm doing this as a learning exercise. Was just wondering why the comparison wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name = '$name_check'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot believe how many other things I tried.

Comment: I recommend you to protect this field. Watch to MySQL Prepared Statements.

Comment: Yeah, that's my next step from here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name = '" . $name_check . "'");
```

Comment: you did not close the opening " before );

Comment: Just forget to end it with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name = '".$name_check."'");
```

This should work fine

Comment: All of the listed answers will work but keep in mind this is a very good case to demonstrate SQL injection. Make sure to sanitize your input values as there could be something malicious put into your form and glean information about your database. Some ways to do this are using data validation before running the insert statement or the use of prepared database statements.